# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). with ajax in caph

Tags: javascript, ajax, server, samsung-smart-tv

I am trying to do an ajax GET request from caph. I am getting the following error

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

For the same url I am getting the response in Browser. Also if I am trying to do the same ajax GET request for the different API on the different server, I am getting the response.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Why you think, that web should be configured equally in both cases - for GET and ajax request?

Comment: Sorry, but couldn't get your point. Can you please explain some more.

Comment: I was missing the Accept Header. Now it is working fine.

Comment: @abhishek - Could you please put your above comment as "Answer" below & mark it as the answer. So that others will be able to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the Accept Header. Now it is working fine.